# Representing inductive types

Tags: coq, agda, dependent-type, idris

I implemented dependently typed lambda calculus in the spirit of this article: http://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/LambdaPi.pdf The calculus, works and I experimented with it and extended with several things: many universes, hardcoded induction axioms. However, I want to add inductive types to do more complex stuff.

I am thinking about two ways of doing so

- Introduce Fin-N, Product and W-types and represent inductive types with them.
- Generate induction and recursion axioms.

I like neither of the ways. The first one is too low level and requires substantial effort for converting from high-level language to the core language. The second way is quite work intensive, and error prone, since generation of recursion principles of complicated inductive types have many corner cases, i.e. positive/negative occurences.

How this can be done? How the types are implemented in existing systems such as Coq, Agda and Idris?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I don't know about Idris.

For Agda, I recommend [Ulf Norell Phd Thesis](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/thesis.pdf) as a starting point, but the system evolved since.

Coq introduces a third bullet in your list: automatically generated predicates.
Each inductive type comes with 3 (1 in some special cases) induction schemes that are automatically defined for the user, and named `your_type_rect`, `your_type_rec` and `your_type_ind` (only the latter one in the special cases). These are actual terms of the languages, generated automatically for the user, and used by the `induction` tactic (I'm not 100% sure about that last one), and not axioms.

In fact you can shut down this automatic generation and write your induction schemes yourself.

Some documentation about `induction` can be found [here](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic71). I advises that you ask your question on the Coq mailing-list, where devs might give you more insight about the internals of Coq.

Best, 
V.

Comment: The coq's approach is the second point. Induction and recursion principles are actually axioms.

Comment: You can actually print the `_rect` `_rec` and `_ind` terms if you want, they are terms of the language. The "correctness" of these schemes involves understanding the `fix` binder and the guard condition, but I don't think they are axioms.